# Why when using ffmpeg to create in real time avi video file from images the avi file is playing with purple noisy color?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ffmpeg

This is my Ffmpeg class i did some time ago

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using DannyGeneral;

namespace Manager
{
    class Ffmpeg
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream p;
        String pipename = "mytestpipe";
        System.Diagnostics.Process process;
        string ffmpegFileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
        string workingDirectory;

        public Ffmpeg()
        {
            workingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            Logger.Write("workingDirectory: " + workingDirectory);
            if (!Directory.Exists(workingDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(workingDirectory);
            }
            ffmpegFileName = Path.Combine(workingDirectory, ffmpegFileName);
            Logger.Write("FfmpegFilename: " + ffmpegFileName);
        }

        public void Start(string pathFileName, int BitmapRate)
        {
            try
            {

                string outPath = pathFileName;
                p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);

                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
                psi.FileName = ffmpegFileName;
                psi.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
                psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v mpeg4 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
                process = Process.Start(psi);
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
                p.WaitForConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Exception Error: " + err.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void PushFrame(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            try
            {
                int length;
                // Lock the bitmap's bits.
                //bmp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
                //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720);
                System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                    bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                    bmp.PixelFormat);

                int absStride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
                // Get the address of the first line.
                IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

                // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
                //length = 3 * bmp.Width * bmp.Height;
                length = absStride * bmpData.Height;
                byte[] rgbValues = new byte[length];

                //Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, length);
                int j = bmp.Height - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
                {
                    IntPtr pointer = new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + (bmpData.Stride * j));
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pointer, rgbValues, absStride * (bmp.Height - i - 1), absStride);
                    j--;
                }
                p.Write(rgbValues, 0, length);
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Error: " + err.ToString());
            }

        }

        public void Close()
        {
            p.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And i'm using it in form1 in a button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
```

the directroy screenshots is where i'm taking a screenshot every 100ms in the timer1 tick event:

```
    ScreenShot shot = new ScreenShot();
    public static int counter = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        shot.GetScreenShot(@"e:\screenshots\", "screenshot");
        if (counter == 1200)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

I'm calling the method PushFrame from inside the ScreenShot class where i save the screenshots.

```
Ffmpeg fmpeg;
```

Then:

```
fmpeg = new Ffmpeg();
fmpeg.Start(@"e:\screenshots\test.avi", 25);
```

And:

```
public Bitmap GetScreenShot(string folder, string name)
    {
        _screenShot = new Bitmap(GetScreen());
        System.GC.Collect();
        System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        string ingName = folder + name + Elgato_Video_Capture.counter.ToString("D6") + ".bmp";
        _screenShot.Save(ingName);
        fmpeg.PushFrame(_screenShot);
        _screenShot.Dispose();

        return _screenShot;
    }
```

All the images on the hard disk are fine i can edit/open them and watch them no problems.
They are also same size.

The result in the end is one big avi file 1.08 GB size.
But when i play it i see many windows running inside very fast and all painted with noisy purple color.

Here a screenshot from the video file when playing it:

[avi file playing screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/t4nfw4563/)

I think the problem is somewhere in the Ffmpeg class where i give parameters to the ffmpeg.exe

```
psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v mpeg4 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
```

Not sure what make this avi file to look like that.

This is the video file the result i got: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdxPus-Xv1k&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Asking SO to find a vague problem in a sizable chunk of code is likely to be somewhat less than productive; can you do some preliminary debugging to at least narrow down which parts of the code appear to be working correctly and which are not?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the problem looks simple... You start taking screen shots and then run FFMpeg to turn them into the AVI, but you aren't finished. Your `ffmpeg.Start()` doesn't wait for all the screen shots, it takes whatever is there. So I'm assuming its a blank directory for the first 99 milliseconds, so its creating a blank AVI file. Don't call your FFMpeg class until you are finished taking all the screen shots.

Comment: Or, call the push frame method, that seems to pass it to the named pipe, you aren't calling it anywhere.

Comment: Right i forgot to call the push frame method. So i did call it now. The result is one big avi file but when i play it i see many windows inside running very fast and it's all painted with purple noise. I will update my question with the result and screenshot of it.

Comment: Edited and upadted my question.  It's creating the avi file but when i play it i see strange screenshots running very very first mixed or screenshots of something else in my desktop and a purple paint noise cover it. I can't upload images to here yet so i gave a link.

Comment: This is a link for a screenshot from the avi file: http://postimg.org/image/t4nfw4563/ and in my OneDrive https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!1344&authkey=!AK_GoncMB3PZxsI&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

Comment: This is the video file the result i got: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdxPus-Xv1k&feature=youtu.be